# some record deleted automatically from my sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

in my database i am having a problem. the problem is that after one or two days i found some records are missing  which are not deleted by me or any user.  how to resolve this problem kindly help

like when i entered data on that time my data is this

```
Enquiry_Id          Day_No   Ckeck_In         Destination
RH - 07/11/2013 - 1   1     2013-12-23           Cochin
RH - 07/11/2013 - 1   2     2013-12-24           Munnar
RH - 07/11/2013 - 1   3     2013-12-25           Kovalam
RH - 14/11/2013 - 2   1     2013-11-21           Thekkady
RH - 14/11/2013 - 2   2     2013-11-22           Munnar
RH - 14/11/2013 - 2   3     2013-11-23           Cochin
```

after 1 or 2 days some records are missing

```
    Enquiry_Id      Day_No   Ckeck_In         Destination
RH - 07/11/2013 - 1   1     2013-12-23           Cochin
RH - 07/11/2013 - 1   2     2013-12-24           Munnar
RH - 07/11/2013 - 1   3     2013-12-25           Kovalam
RH - 14/11/2013 - 2   1     2013-11-21           Thekkady
RH - 14/11/2013 - 2   3     2013-11-23           Cochin
```

like day 2 mising i m working with asp.net(C#). please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Is there any stored procedure responsible for this?

Comment: There has to be something deleting them - either something in your code or a scheduled task on the database.  Without more information its impossible to tell.

Comment: does it happen on random tables or on a specific one? same one all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will never delete data automatically. It has to be something specific.

Followings are some reason that might create problem.

1. Check your delete queries and see whether where clause of that queries are perfect or its deleting another data also.
2. Check background tasks or jobs which may update/delete this data.
3. Check your code where there is a problem with other delete queries or not.

Answer (score 0):

That's kind of strange problem. I would try implementing some logging on the table for which I can see 2 ways:
1) create a trigger for delete on the table that writes date stamp and user stamp to some custom logging table. This approach could provide some basic details.
2) turn on server audit ([SQL Server Audit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx)). This may be pretty cumbersome but if there is no other thoughts...

Also I would check the table dependencies to find all SP that can delete from this table, something that's forgotten :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jalphesh, but if it is critical that the data stays, then you can use a "INSTEAD OF DELETE TRIGGER" to stop it and it should raise an error where it is occurring.  You can also run a trace/(Profiler) on the database to highlight.  Trigger Below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IO_Trig_DEL_Enquiry ON Enquiry
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('DONT DO THIS', -- Message text.
               16, -- Severity.
               1 -- State.
               );
END
```

Remove trigger (obviously) once all is resolved.  You could probably write some server info to a database table for context also.